# Does too much CSS affect performance of a web site?

Tags: html, css

I have researched on this topic and i could not find the exact answer i needed.

For example i have so many divs that need a border. I could write a seperate css class like

```
.border{

    border: solid;
    border-color: #C6C6C6;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
```

and use it in every div tag that needs a border. Or i could include

```
        border: solid;
        border-color: #C6C6C6;
        border-radius: 5px;
```

properties to each and every css class i'm writing for my divs.

By writing a seperate class for border and using it reduces a huge chunk of lines in my css file. But my problem is, will it affect the performance of the web application if i include border properties to each and every css class i write for my divs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it affects at least the traffic, your CSS and HTML should be minified as possible.

Comment: I'd rather combine the things: a `.border` class on each div that needs a border, and an additional class for customizing the things.

Comment: I think it depends on how many different types of border you required, as explained you in your question if you want similar border for multiple divs creating common border class is making sense even though performance point of view as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair this is quite a loaded question...

I don't know if you are aware but CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets, it was built to 'cascade' down from sheet to html tag. So the short answer is no, with today's internet connections, probably not. However here's a few things to consider...

**1) Minifying the CSS** - 
The best way to save on performance using CSS is 'minify' it. There are many online generators that can do this like this one https://cssminifier.com/. This will remove any characters that unnecessarily take up kb in the document, such as spaces and line breaks for example.

**2) User Experience** -
Users in countries like the USA or the United Kingdom now for the most part have access to high-speed broadband, but you must consider that on some very very old connections you'll find that having to re-draw that rule from each tag can take time.

**3) Readability and Debugging** -
If you need to come back tot hat code later and decide that you want to change the border colour, you're doing to have to do that on each and every tag to apply that change as opposed to one simple change on one style sheet. Also if you try to debug this using and kind of in-browser development tool you'll find this is also more complicated that simply looking up one value on one rule instead of however many tabs this is being applied to.

**4) The Cascade Effect** - 
 Finally, this completely defies the point of the CSS model in the first place as their styles trickle down from rule, to style declaration (in the html header), to tag, which makes both documents, not only easy to read but easy to edit too.

So in short, yes there is a performance benefit, but not noticeably so unless on an older connection, but the benefits in other areas of development are much stranger than just the loading speed alone.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes ! Best practice is to have generic class.

Some documentation about CSS methodologies : http://codetheory.in/an-overview-of-oocss-bem-smacss/.

OOCSS, BEM and SMACSS are good methodologies to organize your css.

Answer (score 2):

By writing too many CSS code could make you CSS file size big. If you could avoid duplicate lines of code by creating a class then go for that . It's a best practice to avoid duplicate code so that if any change require with changing one line of code it will reflect every where.
So if it's possible avoid duplicate code. And aways minify your CSS for production website so that CSS file will be smaller as a result page loading time could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying [to solve a problem you're not yet having](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). Don't worry about optimisation until you need to.

On a wider scale, the amount of CSS rules you have *can* affect the load time of your website. When your browser encounters CSS it stops rendering the page, parses the CSS, and builds the CSSOM ([CSS Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model)).

So even if you minify, compress, and merge your CSS files, an excessive amount of CSS could still slow down your website.

It sounds like you're miles away from having to worry about this, though, so don't worry until it becomes a problem (ie. when you have 100s or 1000s if kilobytes of styles).

Answer (score 0):

Without any doubt answer is YES, i have a next js website called [calcgenie](https://www.calcgenie.com/), i tried to rank in google but it didnt happen, so i optimised the css. like 2000 lines to 600 lines of css. it worked like a magic. [check this your doubt](https://www.calcgenie.com/storage-calculators/kb-to-gb)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35560576)